# React native / node issue: The package was successfully found. However, the package specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, react-native, https

I am new to node and React Native and I have an issue that I hope someone can help me resolve.
I and another person are making a React Native application and currently I am trying to piece together a backend made by the other person with my frontend and I get the following error:

While trying to resolve module `http` from file `/Users/alex/ParkME/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js`, the package `/Users/alex/ParkME/node_modules/http/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/alex/ParkME/node_modules/http/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `/Users/alex/ParkME/node_modules/http/index.js(.native||.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.json|.native.expo.json|.expo.json|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
- `/Users/alex/ParkME/node_modules/http/index.js/index(.native||.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.json|.native.expo.json|.expo.json|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install` ?

Comment: @reg Yes, I have

Answer (score 0):

Is the error coming from your backend or frontend code? And were the node modules included in the code you got from the other person? You can try running `npm install` command on the directory to update the dependencies if you haven't already.

Comment: The error is in the frontend, it occurs when I start the Metro Bundler in Expo. The modules are included in the backend code that I got from the other person. (Here in server.js I think: const http = require('http'); )

Unfortunately, I already tried running npm i.

Comment: You ran `install` in the directories for both the front and back end right?

Comment: Can you post the problematic code? http is a core module to node.js so there shouldn't be any issues using it. It could possibly be an issue with the version of node being used. You can check the version with `node -v`

Comment: So, the error occurs when I import createNewSessionRequest() from the api into one of my screens. Here is the api code:

Comment: const params = {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
export const newSessionPath = `http://${ip}:8989/api/newSession`
export function createNewSessionRequest(username) {

  const fetchParams = {
    method: 'POST',
    ...params,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userName: username
    })
  }
  return fetch(newSessionPath, fetchParams)
    .then(response => response)
    .then(res => res.json())
}

Comment: I import from the api via the following command: import { createNewSessionRequest } from '../api.js'